# Retrieve deeply nested sub-document from Document in MongoDB (PHP)

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a collection similar to this:

```
{
'_id': ObjectId("5bc74908f2377d746g1e9983"),
components:{
    0: {
        index: 21,
        abc:22,
        sim: [
            {s_index:23},
            {hyx:45}
        ]
    },
    1: {
        index: 21,
        abc:22,
        sim: [
            {s_index:23},
            {hyx:45}
        ]
    }
   }
}
```

I am trying to output:

```
{
    index: 21,
    abc:22,
         sim: [
             {s_index:23},
             {hyx:45}
        ]
}
```

But with the following query:

```
$Result = $templates -> findOne(
[
    '_id' => new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId("5bc74908f2377d746g1e9983")
],
['projection' => ['_id' => false, 'components.0' => true]]
);
```

I am getting the output as:

```
{
   components:{
    0: {
        index: 21,
        abc:22,
        sim: [
            {s_index:23},
            {hyx:45}
        ]
    }
    }
}
```

**Is there any way to get the desired output?**
I am trying to retrieve just the value of `component.0` but I am getting the complete path in the document.

`sim` is an array of objects. What if I just want to retrieve a particular object in `sim` not the path from components to sim. **Can this be done?**

Comment: With javascript you can do something like this `db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$components",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])`... You can easily convert it to php mongo

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet +1 This worked perfectly how I wanted with $match operation before $replaceRoot. Thanks a lot!